# Select unique set of values from top to bottom

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table containing records in a particular order, and I want to select unique rows having no column with duplicate values.

Like this is my table

[image]

From top to bottom, in each set (ordered by Column2) I need to select unique set if it is not selected before.

The result from above table will be like this

[image]

I tried to use `group by`, `Row_Number`, and `Common Table Expression` but all in vain.

I need single query, no loop or cursor.

Comment: Why there is no `2 2` in example, do you want first unique row in 4 rows chunk?

Comment: Yes, from top, only one from 4 row chunk.

Comment: How do you recognize your sets?

Comment: Why not `SELECT DISTINCT Column1, Column2 FROM dbo.YourTable ORDER BY Column2;`?

Comment: I think it would be easier if you put your logic in a table-function, there you can use loops/multiple queries etc. And then you can call that table-function. It will give you the same desired affect.

Answer (score 0):

Your table miss a column to identify each chunk and to keep order in a chunk.
You can use this kind of query to add thus column

```
select id = identity(int,1,1), *
into new_table
from old_table
```

Then you can use this query

```
with cte as (
Select id, c1, c2, chunck = id/4, rn = row_number() over (partion by c1, c2 order by id) 
from new_table
),
cte2 as (
select c1, c2,  rn2 = row_number() over (partion by chunk order by id)
from cte
where rn=1
)
select c1, c2 
from cte2
where rn2 = 1
```

Comment: An `ORDER BY` is required on the `SELECT...INTO` statement to assign `IDENTITY` values in a particular order.  Otherwise, the values make be assigned in a non-deterministic order.

Comment: Identity column is already there. your query doesn't work. I will work on it and will share with you.

Answer (score 0):

To me this is a very long winded answer, I would use a 'dynamic loop' which would compact most of this code, but you stated that loops aren't possible so... here we go:

```
create table uniq
(
row_id int identity(1,1),
column1 int,
column2 int,
value as (convert(varchar,column1)+''+convert(varchar,column2))
)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (1,1)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (2,2)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (3,3)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (4,4)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (3,1)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (2,2)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (1,3)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (4,4)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (4,1)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (3,2)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (2,3)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (1,4)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (4,1)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (3,2)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (2,3)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (1,4)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (4,1)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (3,2)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (2,3)
insert into uniq (column1,column2) values (1,4)

select value into #1 from uniq where row_id = 1
go
insert into #1
select case when 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 5) not in (select value from #1) 
then 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 5)
else
(
select case when 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 6) not in (select value from #1) 
then 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 6)
else
(
select case when 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 7) not in (select value from #1) 
then 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 7)
else
(select value from uniq where row_id = 8)
end
)
end
)
end
from uniq where row_id = 5
go
insert into #1
select case when 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 9) not in (select value from #1) 
then 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 9)
else
(
select case when 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 10) not in (select value from #1) 
then 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 10)
else
(
select case when 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 11) not in (select value from #1) 
then 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 11)
else
(select value from uniq where row_id = 12)
end
)
end
)
end
from uniq where row_id = 5
go
insert into #1
select case when 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 13) not in (select value from #1) 
then 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 13)
else
(
select case when 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 14) not in (select value from #1) 
then 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 14)
else
(
select case when 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 15) not in (select value from #1) 
then 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 15)
else
(select value from uniq where row_id = 16)
end
)
end
)
end
from uniq where row_id = 5
insert into #1
select case when 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 17) not in (select value from #1) 
then 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 17)
else
(
select case when 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 18) not in (select value from #1) 
then 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 18)
else
(
select case when 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 19) not in (select value from #1) 
then 
(select value from uniq where row_id = 19)
else
(select value from uniq where row_id = 20)
end
)
end
)
end
from uniq where row_id = 5

select left(value,1) as column1,right(value,1) as column2 into #2 from #1

select * from #2
```